# Difference between DbTransaction and DbContextTransaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, effort

When `EntityFramework` query was wrapped in `DbContextTransaction` created with `dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` method I've got the following error:

> at NMemory.Transactions.Transaction.EnsureTransaction(Transaction& transaction, IDatabase database) at NMemory.Tables.Table`2.Update(IQueryable`1 query, IUpdater`1 updater, Transaction transaction) at NMemory.Tables.Table`2.NMemory.Tables.IBulkTable.Update(TableQuery`1 query, Expression`1 updater, Transaction transaction) at NMemory.Linq.QueryableEx.Update[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Expression`1 updater, Transaction transaction) at Effort.Internal.Common.DatabaseReflectionHelper.WrapperMethods.UpdateEntities[TEntity](IQueryable`1 query, Expression`1 updater, Transaction transaction)

I found a post on *Effort* GitHub repository with similar error (https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort/issues/29) where it was fixed using `DbTransaction` instead, created by `dbContext.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction()` method. I tried using `DbTransaction` instead and it works, but now I'm wondering what's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 0):

If we take the documentation for [DbTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbtransaction?view=net-6.0) and [DbContextTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontexttransaction?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) we have:

**DbTransaction**:

- Defines the **core behavior** of **database transactions** so it's independant from EntityFramework and comes from *System.Data.Common*
- you have some additionnals methods like **CommitAsync**, **DisposeAsync**, **SaveAsync**, ... and implements the interface **IdbTransaction**

**DbContextTransaction**:

- Comes from *System.Data.Entity*
- Implement **IDisposable** only

I found another explanation here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24074

> Beginning a transaction on Database is an EF Core
> API which will internally call the corresponding lower-level ADO.NET
> DbConnection API. It's recommended to use DbContextTransaction, that way EF Core is properly aware that a transaction
> has been started - that can be important depending on exactly how you
> use the DbContext.

Comment: Please link to English sites. Also, an important difference is that DbcontextTransaction is part of the old EF6.